# doesn't show username of a user that has just logged in, but shows their profile picture

Tags: session, flask, async-await

When a user successfully logs in, they see some kind of a greeting with their picture and "Hello, username!" text. But the problem is that sometimes it doesn't show their username (just "Hello, !") but their **profile picture is always shown**. I made JS script wait 200ms (gave it some time to pass the username to a greeting div) but it didn't solve the problem.

P.S. I noticed that it happens when I pop the user out of the session and restart the server. If I don't restart the server but log out and log in again then it's okay - I can see my username in a greeting div.

Here's the code:

**routes.py**

```
loginForm = LoginForm.from_json(req)
   
sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=%s"
cur.execute(sql, (loginForm.log_username.data))
row_headers = [x[0] for x in cur.description]
user = cur.fetchone()
       
if user:
    user = dict(zip(row_headers, user))
    
    if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user['password_hash'], loginForm.log_password.data):
        session['username'] = user['username']
        session['picture'] = user['picture']
```

**login.html**

```
if (response.ok) {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            go();  // function that shows the greeting div
        }, 200);
} else {
```

**greeting div** in login.html

```
<div class="greet">
    <img class="photo rounded-full mx-auto" src="{{ url_for('static', filename=session['picture']) }}" alt="">
    
    <div class="text-center font-medium text-base">
        Hello, {{ session['username'] }}!
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to diagnose:

```
print(user)
if user:
    user = dict(zip(row_headers, user))
    print(user)
```

Comment: You are going to have to so up the tree to the query, to see what it is returning

Comment: everything is absolutely okay. Maybe it's because the greeting div appears on the same page as the login form, and to use session I need to reload page?